# Why TurnAround Time is considered as Performance Metric for Scheduling Algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, process-scheduling

I know what is turn around time but i am confused why wating time is not considred as Performance Metric for Scheduling Algorithms Since it gives the time for which a Process will wait till it gets Scheduled...This can also be Performance Metric

Comment: It's probably also considered as a performance metric.

Comment: (That's a lot of capital letters.) With preemption, *time to first action* is trivial to minimise.

Comment: (In interactive environments, *time to first (incomplete/imperfect) result* definitely _is_ a metric. Not sure about real-time.)

Comment: Why do you think it can't be considered as a performance metric?

Comment: I finally found out that TAT , WT, Response Time(RT) are all different methods of evulating performance of Scheduling Algorithms... Wating Time(WT) gives the time a process waits in READY state...and hence can be used for evulating diiferent Scheduling Techniques

Comment: @YuvalFilmus you are Correct

Comment: @D.W. I was little confused